# Unable to execute a .bat file in post build event command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, msbuild, post-build-event

My post build command is

```
call "$(ProjectDir)MyFile.bat"
```

And getting build error:

> Error    1    The command "call
>   C:\MyProject\MyFile.bat"
>   exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4548    5

What am I missing here? Working on TFS source code, is that the reason getting this error?

For testing in `MyFile.bat` the only code is `mkdir MYTestFolder`, but  then I am also getting the same error.

Comment: This question seems to indicate my answer is completly wrong, but then I would say the call to the batch file is working, but the batch is failing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491394/can-we-execute-a-bat-file-in-post-build-event-command-line-in-visual-studio

Comment: `mkdir` is not a complete batch command.

Comment: sorry for typo i did it like `mkdir MYTestFolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the syntax of the call is correct. Therefore I believe it's failing inside the batch file. I suggest putting the first few lines of the batch to write the time into a log file, so you can confirm it's being called. Do this before any of the actual work, so it can be sure that the batch is being executed.

```
call "$(ProjectDir)MyFile.bat"
```

#### MyFile.bat

```
@echo off
echo time /t > MyTempFolderPath\logfile.txt
```

Comment: getting same error.. is it necessary to execute `cmd.exe` before `.bat`?
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe call MyFile.bat` ?? is it ?

Comment: for testing in MyFile.bat only code is `mkdir MyTestFolder`  then also getting same error

Comment: I have zero ideas left. It seems like everything should work.

Comment: same here :( i dont know how and where to troubleshoot :/

Comment: Also we can use this to run build events in Debug only 
```if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
call "$(ProjectDir)prebuild.bat"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the code inside the batch file that is failing - what is it doing?

You have a few options:

a - I would use process monitor and watch process exits and see the status codes of whatever the batch file launches.

b - You could also try running the batch file from the same folder as msbuild and see if you get any errors

Ed

Comment: for testing in MyFile.bat only code is `mkdir MyTestFolder` then also getting same error

Comment: I guess that it can't find MyFile.bat - use procmon and setup a filter for "path contains MyFile.bat" - $(ProjectDir) probably isn't resolving either at all or where you think it is See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985900/tfs-msbuild-projectdir-blank-or-random)

Comment: in procmon unable to find file `MyFIle.bat` ?